# Scrolling video back and forth with script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

Is there any way to emulate this kind of [360 degree product view](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/) scroll/drag functionality with video, so taking a piece of video and being able to scroll it left and right as though it was a set of images? I've found [this tutorial](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-interactive-street-view-jquery) which is about the 360langstrasse.sf.tv/page/ site which is pretty interesting, but it's pretty custom to their specific needs and pretty complex. Is there any way to just take some video and have the kind of left/right scroll/drag functionality that you would get with an image-based 360 degree script? I would just like a little video to load in a placeholder, and then you can drag it left and right.

I've thought about converting frames to jpegs and then stitching them into a panorama, but that gets very big very quickly. Would prefer a video solution, where one can just drag the video itself.

Comment: I've done something simulair for a mobile based project. We went with splitting the video up in jpg's and making a scrolling paralex. Wich worked perfectly, but loading times were huge, so we added an imagepreloader as a splashscreen. Very interested in knowing if there's a viable video sollution to this problem aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You could shoot the video of the object spinning. Then play it forwards for spinning one way and reverse for spinning another.

Using 2 videos could also work - one for spinning one way and the other video the opposite way.

This is possible in Flash but I'm not sure about HTML5 video across browser vendors.

[Is it possible to play HTML5 video in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277293/is-it-possible-to-play-html5-video-in-reverse)