# html5 video and javascript combination fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am working on a HTML5 video functionality and I have a question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053261/play-a-video-in-reverse-using-html5-video-element) asking the approach to be followed.

Found some semi-helping articles on w3.org website but found a completely working example on jsfiddle.net

Please follow the link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/28/)

I am trying the same as follows in my local machine -

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var video = document.getElementById('video').play();
var intervalRewind;
$(video).on('play', function () {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
$(video).on('pause', function () {
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
$("#speed").click(function () { // button function for 3x fast speed forward
    video.playbackRate = 3.0;
});
$("#negative").click(function () { // button function for rewind   
    intervalRewind = setInterval(function () {
        video.playbackRate = 1.0;
        if (video.currentTime == 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalRewind);
            video.pause();
        } else {
            video.currentTime += -.1;
        }
    }, 30);
});    
});
</script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <video id="video" controls>
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<button id="speed">Fast Forward</button>
<button id="negative">Rewind</button>   
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to find out why and where this script is failing. Is jquerymobile a problem?
Expected: Both Forward and Reverse functionalities should work.
Actual: None of the two buttons are working.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You script worked (more or less), all it took to make it work was to comment out setting playback rate on play event. It was interfering with setting playback rate after clicking fast-forward. Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/32/

As to the script itself, you should realize, that your rewind implementation has some flaws. One of them is that video is actually paused the whole time, so user can't just press pause to stop rewinding. But that would be easily solvable. The other, bigger issue is, that while doing a rewind you hop back in time by `.1` fraction. That may or may be not an issue for some setups/movies. For those shorter movies your rewind function might be to speedy.

Comment: Understood. The second part of the issues, hopping back by .1 fraction, I did see that the rewind is speedy. This happens on a chrome browser too. How can I control this?
Also, is there a way to "reverse play" on load directly?