# play html5 video in reverse, on screen load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am working on a functionality where on my screen load, a video should start playing reverse. (from its last frame to the first frame).
It can actually be on screen load or even on a button click.

At this moment, I've achieved until (with the help and support from StackOverflow) playing my video - and playing it in reverse after some duration of time. Here's the code I used-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
video{
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

var video = document.getElementById('video');
var intervalRewind;
$(video).on('play',function(){
    //video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
$(video).on('pause',function(){
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
$("#speed").click(function() { // button function for 3x fast speed forward
    video.playbackRate = 8.0;
});
$("#negative").click(function() { // button function for rewind
   intervalRewind = setInterval(function(){
       video.playbackRate = 1.0;
       if(video.currentTime == 0){
           clearInterval(intervalRewind);
           video.pause();
       }
       else{
           video.currentTime += -.1;
       }
                },30);
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>



<video id="video" controls>
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
        <button id="speed">Fast Forward</button>
        <button id="negative">Rewind</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I would like to know if there is a chance to play my video in reverse directly i.e. without progressing any duration in the forward direction, the video should start playing in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until video is loaded, then you can get it's length with `video.duration` and then you can set the video current time to this value (Jump to end of the video);

Then you can start playing the video from last frame to first using your negative function.

```
  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
     video.currentTime = video.duration;
     $('#negative').click();
  }, false);
```

There is also nice fiddle about video playbacks at http://jsfiddle.net/UkMV2/5/ found from [play a video in reverse using HTML5 video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053261/play-a-video-in-reverse-using-html5-video-element)

Following example is super slightly modified version of your's which achieves the "reverse" playback upon page & video loaded event.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
video{
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <video id="video" controls>
      <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
  <button id="speed">Fast Forward</button>
  <button id="negative">Rewind</button>


  <script>
  $(function() {

  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var intervalRewind;


  $(video).on('play',function(){
      //video.playbackRate = 1.0;
      clearInterval(intervalRewind);
  });
  $(video).on('pause',function(){
      video.playbackRate = 1.0;
      clearInterval(intervalRewind);
  });
  $("#speed").click(function() { // button function for 3x fast speed forward
      video.playbackRate = 8.0;
  });
  $("#negative").click(function() { // button function for rewind
     intervalRewind = setInterval(function(){
         video.playbackRate = 1.0;
         if(video.currentTime == 0){
             clearInterval(intervalRewind);
             video.pause();
         }
         else{
             video.currentTime += -.1;
         }
                  },30);
  });

  video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
     video.currentTime = video.duration;
     $('#negative').click();
  }, false);



  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just noticed this was asked almost 4 years ago, still popped at me in latest jQuery questions :) Well no harm in answering I guess