# reverse video when finished with javascript

Tags: javascript, video, reverse

Hi I have a video playing. When it finishes it restarts (loop) and this causes a small jumping of the animation.

I'd like to reverse the video when it finishes. I have used a regular video tag:

```
<video id="myvideok" src="video/ORG.mp4"  >
    This is fallback content to display for user agents that do not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and my javascript is:

```
myvideok.play(); 

myvideok.onended = function(e) {
    myvideok.playbackRate = -1;
    myvideok.play();
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.
any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Reverse it? as in play it backwards? I doubt that's possible. Sounds like you need to clean up the animation to make it run smoothly. Either that or encode a reversed version of the video and add it to the playlist loop

Comment: hi, yes i'd like to play it in reverse.i fell on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053261/play-a-video-in-reverse-using-html5-video-element but with no success

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the variable `myvideok` to the player with

```
var myvideok = document.getElementById("myvideok");
```

Comment: hi, yes i set it like that.

Comment: Looks like the playbackRate only supports reverse playback on certain browsers. I'm messing around with my own videos and it looks like that's the only problem. Setting the playbackRate to anything above 0 has an effect, but anything below 0 keeps the speed where it was.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not supported in your browser.
look at this [Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

You can set the audio or video playbackRate property to nonzero values to play media in slow motion (values >0 and <1) or fast forward (values >1) in Safari on the desktop. Setting playbackRate is not currently supported on iOS.