# HTML5 video playing backward, detect "end" of video

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make video player where, when you click on backward button, it will go backwards, and when it hits 00:00 time, it change video source and starts to play another video.

Asume that list of videos can be js array. When you are on video2, you hit backward. Video2 is going backward and when it hit 00:00, it swap source to video1. And video1 will be playing backward.

```
var vids = [
   "video1",
   "video2",
   "video3",
   "video4"
];
```

According to my research, HTML5 video supports onended() function when you can detect normal end of video, but it does not solve it for end in backward direction.

According to this thread [play-a-video-in-reverse-using-html5-video-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053261/play-a-video-in-reverse-using-html5-video-element).
Browsers currently do not support playing video backward. There is only one way how to manage it by faking current time in video. See how it looks like in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UkMV2/5/

Use of onended() function when video plays forward, and put another video when that before ends is easy. But how to detect that video ended in start?

I will appreciate any suggestions which can move me forward.

Comment: Since you're faking the current time, can't you tell when you're faking 0:00?

Comment: curious: have you tried a negative playbackrate?

Comment: Mike McCaughan: I can, but when I decide go in forward direction then, and it hit new video 00:00 it will behave like, start backward video, but it should not

Comment: dandavis: Video will go backward, but when it hits 00:00 it stops and nothing happens. But I want to switch source of videos.