# HTML5 Video Reverse like Apple website

Tags: html, video, html5-video, reverse

I've been trying to replicate this effect apple has on their website. I have been able to do the stop & start effectively on scroll but the reverse playback is an issue.

I've searched and old solutions on the website point to a reverse video which i've done but given that apple has done it for both ipad air and mac pro, I am sure there is a new solution.

Do let me know if you have been able to figure it out. I checked the website, they only use one video.

Thank you so much.

[Apple reference](http://www.apple.com/ipad-air/)

Answer (score 0):

Neat. So they have one big video file (named 'story.mp4') which contains all the transitions. Then have code that can ask the video to play from one point in the file to another point, rather than playing from start straight through to finish.

But you've figured out that much and you want to know how to play parts of the video in reverse? Perhaps this question and answer will help: [Is it possible to play HTML5 video in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277293/is-it-possible-to-play-html5-video-in-reverse) According to that, it comes down to setting the media element's `playbackRate` to -1.