# Play video on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, scroll, mousewheel

I'm trying to play a video while I scroll. Anyhow I achieved to play it forwards but when I scroll backwards the video doesn't play backwards, instead it plays forwards.

Here is my code :

```
//getting video element
var v = $("#v");

// calling function on scroll
$("#video-wrapper").on('mousewheel','#v',function(){
    var playVideoByScrollv = new PlayVideoByScrollv(v);
});

var PlayVideoByScrollv = function(video,e){

    var evt=window.event || e //equalize event object
    //delta returns +120 when wheel is scrolled up, -120 when scrolled down
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta 

    if(delta<=-120){
       video.currentTime += (1 / 24);
       video[0].play();
       setTimeout(function(){
           video[0].pause();
       },40);
    }
    else{
       video.currentTime -= (1 / 24);
       video[0].play();
       setTimeout(function(){
           video[0].pause();
       },40);
    }

    if (evt.preventDefault) //disable default wheel action of scrolling page
        evt.preventDefault()
    else
        return false
}
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to archive, I imagin you want to control a video by scrolling up or down.

I found a video on Youtube, on how to build a video control by scrolling. You may be interested:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiegEfkenXA

Here is a simple code-snippet I've done:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
        body {
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }

        #v0 {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top:0px;
            width: 70%;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div style="height:1600vh; text-align: center;">
    <video id="v0" tabindex="0", autobuffer preload>
        <source type='video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2&quot;' src="https://www.apple.com/media/us/mac-pro/2013/16C1b6b5-1d91-4fef-891e-ff2fc1c1bb58/videos/macpro_main_desktop.mp4"></source>
    </video>
</div>



    <script>

        // start video at frame 0
        var frameNumber = 0,
        
        // lower numbers = faster playback
        playbackConst = 800, 

        // select video element         
        vid = document.getElementById('v0'); 
        


    // Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
    function scrollPlay(){  
    var frameNumber  = window.pageYOffset/playbackConst;
    vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code sets the current time to either to a new time in the future (when you scroll forwards) and a new time in the past (when you scroll backwards). In both cases it will then start to play the video as normal (i.e. forwards).

If you want to actually play the video backwards you will probably find it quite a problem as most encoding techniques assume playing forwards - for example the 9th frame may be built by taking the 6th frame and adding some info from the 7th frame and the 8th frame first and then info for the 9th frame.

For streamed videos it is even more of an issue as the streams will almost all be set up to play forwards only.

There are some approaches (see answers at: [Is it possible to play HTML5 video in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5277293/334402)) but I doubt if any of these are what you are looking for.