# HTML5 360 Video Reverse Play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Is there any way to reverse play 360 videos with HTML5? jwplayer, kolor eyes, krpano not supporting 360 rewind play.

I found HTML5 reverse play on [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/qmCek) How can I implement 360 video player with this code?

Comment: A web search for "rewind play 360 videos with HTML5" shows some results. You need to tell us why some of those results do not apply.

Comment: I'm looking for reverse play of the 360 video with HTML5 support. Nothing in the Google search results is related, that's why I'm asking here again. If you have some answers I'd be pleased to hear.

Comment: Comments can be deleted. You need to clearly state in the body of the question what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: For example, how is https://github.com/paypal/accessible-html5-video-player not related? Are there hints there? Basically, show some of the research you've done.

Comment: Do you know 360 videos? Because your example is not compatible with 360. Another problem reverse play. Your example  only html5 video player. Read my question

Comment: Comments are not answers. The greater point is that it is unclear how much research has been done here. I don't think there is enough information because I think you have to consider the underlying container. Streaming formats are going to be a challenge https://stackoverflow.com/q/5277293/1531971

Comment: Its not 360° video player.

Comment: Did you even read those links? You are going to have to expand your search to beyond things that specifically talk about an ill defined definition of "360". Ask yourself what a so-called 360 video is.  I bet it's a streaming format, and HTML5 probably sees it as a MIME type. I'd work from there.