# Play video backwards after playback

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm working on a website, and it has a video that is loaded as a background on the home.

The video is short, lasts 10 seconds, I need to know if there is any way to make the video play normally, and when it reaches the end it will automatically rewind, and then start again.

Because the way it is now, it reaches the end and starts playing again from the beginning again, then the cut appears. Is this possible via html5?

The video is playing this way:

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="header-home-bg-video">
          <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to play HTML5 video in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277293/is-it-possible-to-play-html5-video-in-reverse)

Comment: I didn't get it that way