# Toggle reverse video with JQuery onclick

Tags: jquery

I have an html video and I have been manipulating the speed of playback, I understand by using a minus numeric value the video can play in reverse. On click of the video I would like to toggle the playback to play backwards or forwards respectfully.

```
$('video').click(function(){
   $('.slow-video').toggleProp({
      playbackRate: -0.6,
      playbackRate: 0.6
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I understand by using a minus numeric value the video can play in reverse

This is incorrect. Setting a negative `playbackRate` does not play the video in reverse, source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate)

There are methods to play videos backwards, but they are rather *hacky* - [Is it possible to play HTML5 video in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5277293/519413)